# Propositional truncation vs. Zero Knowledge Proofs

Tags: computational-complexity, cryptography, homotopy-type-theory

**Disclaimer:** This question is vague. It reports on a curious similarity in the hope that discussion might perhaps turn it into something more rigorous, but it's entirely possible that there's nothing to be found here. Equally, perhaps it's well-understood and I'm just not aware.

The curious similarity is between homotopy type theory and zero knowledge proofs:

In Homotopy Type Theory, there's the concept of Propositional Truncation. Informally, one forgets all homotopical structure of a type and only cares whether it's inhabited or not. Formally, for a type $X$, its propositional truncation is the initial map $X\to\|X\|$ into a propositional type $\|X\|$ (where a proposition is a type where all elements are equal). Intuitively (to me, at least), proving $\|\|$ proves $X$. without exhibiting a specific witness in $X$.

In Cryptography, the concept of Zero Knowledge does something very similar: Informally, proving a proposition in zero knowledge demonstrates that the proposition is true without revealing a witness to the verifier.

Conceptually, both things seem very close, and I wonder if there's some formal connection that can be drawn here, such as a cryptographically motivated semantics for Homotopy Type Theory (which would necessarily take computational complexity into account). Higher dimensional structures have also entered computational complexity in the form of higher dimensional expanders, amplifying my curiosity further.

Comment: The similarity is superficial (maybe not even that). As with so many things in cryptography, zero-knowledge proof protocols are concerned with _practical_ computability, i.e. algorithmic complexity. Computational interpretations of type theory are not - a proof is a proof, no matter how long it is!

Comment: Of course, but why could computational complexity not enter the interpretation?

Answer (score 3):

> Intuitively (to me, at least), proving $∥X∥$ proves $X$ without exhibiting a specific witness in $X$.

This is not correct. In a constructive theory, there's no way to exhibit $\Vert X \Vert$ without exhibiting an $X$, and someone consuming your construction of $\Vert X \Vert$ will have access to the $X$ you constructed.

What $\Vert X \Vert$ does is add equivalences such that distinct $X$ values produce equivalent proofs of $\Vert X \Vert$ (and so on). This also means that someone consuming your $\Vert X \Vert$ construction must produce a result that is equivalent to results based on any other $X$ value. However, this doesn't mean that they don't get to know which $X$ you used.

One way of seeing this is with a type like $\Vert Σ_{n:ℕ} P(n) \Vert$, where $P$ somehow characterizes a unique natural number. In this case, it is possible to extract the natural number in question. In a proof assistant, this might look something like:

```
f : || Σ ℕ P || → ℕ
f | n , _ | = n
...
```

where the ellipses handle the formal paths added by the truncation. Note that the case for the base points just extracts the numeric witness, suggesting that the base point proofs of $\Vert Σ_{n:ℕ} P(n) \Vert$ are *actually represented* (in part) by numbers. The cases in the ellipses just constitute a proof that the same number will be extracted from every point, so that it is okay for this function to be admitted. And evaluating this function on a proof will extract the (uniquely determined) number used to prove it.

If $P$ is decidable, then it's actually possible to write a similar function even if $P$ does not determine a unique number, because any proof gives us *some* $n$ that satisfies $P$, and we can search for the least $m$ that satisfies $P$ below it.

A zero-knowledge proof seems more analogous to double negation in an intuitionistic setting. $(X → ⊥) → ⊥$ is always a proposition, and without double negation elimination, you cannot extract an $X$ from it, even in the sort of scenarios above. You may imagine that a value of that type just calls a function with a given value (although that is not really a sensible interpretation in general), but there is no mechanism for inspecting a function to observe which value it is using.

However, as Zhen Lin mentioned, zero-knowledge proofs usually incorporate a tractability aspect that is not automatically incorporated into existing type theories. A function implemented by brute force is the same *function* as one implemented using secret knowlege to solve the problem efficiently. So to properly incorporate this aspect, you'd need to model runtime complexity somehow in a type theory, or design a theory that has complexity as an inherent aspect.

Edit: perhaps I should note, much of the above is still similar even classically. You can still 'extract' a $ℕ$ from a truncation if it is uniquely characterized, as if values of the truncation contained numbers. And $((X → ⊥) → ⊥) → X$ for $X$ that are not propositions is a choice principle that you might not admit. However, what is different is that you may not need to exhibit an $X$ to prove $\Vert X \Vert$. However, this is not limited to truncation. Instead it leads to, for instance, definitions of natural numbers that don't have a definite corresponding construction.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Dan. Regarding "To properly incorporate this aspect, you'd need to model runtime complexity somehow in a type theory, or design a theory that has complexity as an inherent aspect.": Not necessarily as part of the type theory itself, or? Rather as part of a _model_ that wants to stand a chance of interpreting $\|-\|$ as anything like ZKPs, I thought. I fail to convince myself why such model isn't inconceivable.

Comment: I just refreshed my memory a bit on ZKPs, and there seem to be a lot of details that do not match type theoretic proofs well at all. For instance, if Peggy proves something to Victor, Victor must not be able to use a recording of the proof to convince anyone else that Peggy _can_ prove the proposition. It is apparently insufficient to merely prevent Victor from pretending he has the secret. This doesn't seem like it matches the way you can just hand values around and duplicate them in (most) type theory very well.

Comment: I agree with most of this, but to be precise I think "there's no way to exhibit $\Vert \Vert$ without exhibiting an $X$" is really only true in the empty context, and even there "someone consuming your construction of $\Vert X\Vert$ will have access to the $X$ you constructed" refers to the computational behavior of your $X$ rather than to any internally provable property it might have or fail to have (since anything internal you can say about an $\Vert X\Vert$ must be independent of which one you have).

Comment: "What ‖‖ does is add equivalences such that distinct  values produce equivalent proofs of ‖‖" But this already assumes a specific way of constructing the truncation. If you see it / construct it as adding equivalences, then yes, the underlying points are "still there". But why couldn't there be other constructions? Think what ZKPs do (probablistically, interactively -- this would need modelling somehow) to hide information ...

Comment: ... the prover commits to a proof/witness by communicating e.g. a hash, and then the verifier asks the prover to selectively open parts of it. Even if you make this non-interactive e.g. via the Fiat-Shamir transform, you get a proof string (in |X|) which is impossible/infeasible to construct unless you started with an actual proof (in X), while it's also infeasible/impossible (depending on the construction) to reconstruct the former from the latter.

Comment: 'Exhibit' was probably not the best word choice. I meant to be talking about how you should think about 'values' of the type. Also, I rather thought the computational behavior or 'mental model' sort of thing was the whole point of this question, and whether or not it matches some other semantic sort of notion, not internally provable properties.

Comment: Also, @Hanno, the problem with your hypothetical 'other construction' is that there are ways in the type theory of getting an $X$ out of a $\Vert X \Vert$, under certain conditions. And the expected calculation rules say, I think, that you get the same $X$ out that was put in, on the nose. So, truncation does _not_ make it infeasible to reconstruct the original value (in general). That is why I mentioned double negation, which does behave more like that, at least in a constructive setting. But perhaps some other type would be better (a right adjoint where truncation is left, perhaps).

Comment: @DanDoel Can you elaborate how type theory enables "getting an X out of |X|"? This seems wrong to me.

Comment: If $X$ is a proposition, then the elimination principle of $\Vert X \Vert$ allows extracting an $X$. Further, if you have a function $f : A → B$ where $A$ and $B$ are sets, and a proof that $f$ is injective and surjective, where surjective is $Π y:B. \Vert Σ x:A. y = f x \Vert$, then you can derive an inverse function $g : B → A$. This involves extracting $A$ values from the truncation, which is allowed because injectivity and set-hood of $A$ and $B$ imply that the Σ type is a proposition.

Comment: Yes, but I feel that those are special cases not relevant to the question (?) - it's clear that a proposition is its own truncation.

Comment: @DanDoel It seems the propositional truncation only eliminates to mere proposition? If that was the case, the content of the proof can only be *extracted* in the context of mere propositions (and thus cannot actually escape the truncation?) In terms of, say, at runtime, it will be information-less/can be erased/zero-bit (if the compiler is smart enough). (Disclaimer: I am still learning the Book so maybe I am being naive)

Comment: No. This seems predicated on the idea that 'mere propositions' carry no information, and can be erased. But this is simply wrong.